# utility for use docker instead of classic setup ( wamp, mamp, lamp)

Tags: node.js, docker, wamp, mamp, lamp

I have a question.

I'm a web developper since 5 years and i develop locally with the classic setup that is to say wamp/mamp/lamp under the OS and i use git also.

For ship the source code, i push the code to the git server and i pull it from my server of production.

I have a utility for let my classic setup for docker, if i have a utility can you tell me what because after read many article on Internet, i have seen how set a container but i don't see utily for me :/

PS : If my English if no good, I'm sorry, i'm French and my english is not perfect.

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if you want to deploy with using docker, the build artifact is your docker image.

The advantage of doing it this way, is that your tooling is the same no matter what language your code is written in. It does not matter if it is an interpreted language, or compile language, you always get a docker image that is the build artifact.

A fairly common pattern is to commit your code to git, and then have a ci/cd pipeline that will build an image that contains your application, and push it out to a Docker registry so that it can be used in your deployments.

You can even use the same image while doing development work. This reduces the time it takes for a developer to get a development environment working on their workstation.

One of the biggest advantages in this case is you get consistency from the application's point of view from inside the container. It does not matter if you are on a server, or a developer laptop. It all looks the same because it is the same image, with the same dependencies in that image.

Comment: Okay ! 

So if i understand, for begin development i take or i create a docker image who contains the environment of application ( for exemple for a PHP application, a image with apache, mysql and PHP and for finish a git clone for download from git the last version of my application ?)

If it's that, it's a good tool :)

Last Question, the good practice it's make a container for each element of environment ( 1 container for apache, one for mysql, etc ...) or a container who contains all elements ?

Thank you for answer.

Comment: I recommend putting each service in your application into its own container. If my application needs mysql, apache, and redis, then I would end up with three containers: mysql, apache, and redis

Comment: Thank you for answer, with your information, i go to learn for use docker and the tool docker-compose.